# django-pipeline wipes out my entries in Django Database Cache

Tags: python, django, django-database, django-cache, django-pipeline

I'm working on a `Django` application which uses `django-pipeline` for dealing with browsers' file caching issues (and also for other benefits).

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'bower'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.CachedFileFinder',
)

PIPELINE = {}
PIPELINE['DISABLE_WRAPPER'] = True
PIPELINE['JS_COMPRESSOR'] = 'pipeline.compressors.NoopCompressor'
PIPELINE['CSS_COMPRESSOR'] = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'

PIPELINE['COMPILERS'] = (
    'pipeline.compilers.sass.SASSCompiler',
    'pipeline.compilers.es6.ES6Compiler',
)

PIPELINE['JAVASCRIPT'] = {
...
}

PIPELINE['STYLESHEETS'] = {
...
}

PIPELINE['SASS_BINARY'] = 'C:\\Ruby22-x64\\bin\\sass.bat'
PIPELINE['BABEL_BINARY'] = 'c:\\Users\\Foobar\\node_modules\\.bin\\babel.cmd'
```

So far so good. Lately we decided to use Django's Database Cache (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#database-caching) for caching some long running statistical calculation results.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'django_dbcache',
    }
}
```

I executed `createcachetable` and the table was created. I'm placing entries into this table with no expiration date, since I have my own validity check, and can decide myself if the data is up-to-date, or needs to be recalculated.

To my surprise however, when I issue a `collectstatic` for `pipeline`, it wipes the content of that table and fills it with it's own `staticfiles:{md5code}` key-values. (In production I saw situation when it didn't wipe out everything). But this renders my caching scheme non functional. I cannot seem to find any settings in the pipeline documentation how to stop `pipeline` doing this. `pipeline`'s cache entry values in the cache are pretty short, merely contain full path to generated files. These entries' expiration are a couple of hours. I won't mind them being there, just don't wipe my stuff.

---

Additional note: I'm on Windows platform (see the pipeline settings above), but the same thing happens on a Linux production server.

---

Addition to the marked answer: knowing that anyone can mess with the default cache + staticfiles can rudely wipe it out, it's even better to separate ours and everyone else:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'default-cache',
    },
    'staticfiles': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'static-files',
    },
    'my_dbcache': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'django_dbcache',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a separate cache for static files will fix the issue. Django by default looks for "staticfiles" cache first.
example:

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
    'LOCATION': 'django_dbcache',
},
'staticfiles': {
    'BACKEND': "django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache",
    'LOCATION': 'static-files',
}
```